# create Mat from a pointer, resize it and return pointer to the new mat

Tags: c#, opencv

something weird is happening to me with the Mat of opencv when i resize the Mat.

this is the header in opencv:
first i receive a pointer from my managed code in visual c#:

```
 unsigned char *  PointerImage( unsigned char*  matData, int widht)
```

i create a Mat from the pointer in opencv:

```
 cv::Mat OriginalImg(Size(widht,widht),CV_8UC3,matData);
```

If i don´t apply the resize and i send the pointer to my Mat created to my program in visual c#, it works fine, and i can show the image in my visual c#.

```
 unsigned char *data = OriginalImg.data;
```

the problem begin when i apply the resize to put the image bigger :

```
cv::resize( OriginalImg, OriginalImg, size(270,270));
```

Now i can´t see the image .

here is the entire code:

```
  unsigned char *  PointerImage( unsigned char*  matData, int widht){

    cv::Mat OriginalImg(Size(widht,widht),CV_8UC3,matData);
    cv::resize( OriginalImg, OriginalImg, size);
    unsigned char *data = OriginalImg.data;

    return data;

}
```

i doubt about the pointer when i apply the resize.
thanks.

Comment: ouuch. that looks like terribly broken design

Comment: cv::resize might reallocate OriginalImg. but if so, OriginalImg gets destroyed when you're leaving the PointerImage function and yuo're left with a dangling data ptr.

Comment: I thought the same, i apply the advice of marol and now it works fine. thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @berak is quite right. You have a memory leak in your code. You cannot return a pointer to the **local** variable data created in the function. The destructor of OriginalImg object is fired when program gets out of PointerIMage function scope. The memory is released, so does OriginalImg.data, making this pointer unavialable.

Please consoder using global variable in your c++ code (in fact not good solution) or encapsulate your c++ code in the class which you can later use in c# (depends how you call the native code form .NET).

Comment: thanks you very much, when i create a global Matrix and copy the data of originalImg in it, then resize and return the pointer it works fine. thanks